# Why do I have an ESLint Error - overrideConfigFile?

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

My settings.json:

```
  "eslint.options": {
"overrideConfigFile": {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-debugger": "off"
  }
}
```

},

My previous ESLint errors were that 'env', 'parserOptions' and 'rules' had to be wrapped in an overrideConfigFile which fixed those errors, now I'm getting error "ESLint: Invalid Options: - 'overrideConfigFile' must be a non-empty string or null..". Has anybody come across this or understand why this isn't working? Google isn't being my friend & changing overrideConfigFile to be null or empty string would just bring about the previous errors.

Comment: Shouldn't overrideConfigFile be a _file_, or in this case the _path_ to one? That would explain why it wants a non-empty string.

Comment: Ah ok - so do you think these settings should be in a separate document and the value for overrideConfigFile is the path to that file?